# React js importing HTML won't run script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

In my App.js I am importing an HTML file:

```
import __html from './pages/animation/index.html';
var template = { __html: __html };
```

And I return it in the view

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />
```

index.html:

```
<body>

    <h1>TEXT</h1>

    <script>

        console.log("Hello");

    </script>
    
</body>
```

The rendering of the file works since I can see the h1, yet the script won't run.

Answer (score 0):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

in `__html:` for security reasons script tags not executed because injected via innerHTML